# Nginx - Limit number of letters in subdomain

Tags: nginx

I would like any subdomains less than six characters to return a 404 -

for example, `abcd.example.com` should return a 404, but `stackoverflow.example.com` to return the index.html

I've tried the following -

```
location ~ ^/[a-z0-9-_]{0,2}$
  return 404;
}
```

This gives me an error - `unknown directive "0,2}$"`

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can spot a couple of syntax errors in your code:

1. Nginx uses curly braces `{` `}` to specify internal directives so when you are using `{0,2}` it is trying to read that as a directive - you would need to double quote to avoid this;
2. After your `$` you should have a `{` to open up the directive for your `location` statement.

However the biggest problem is that `location` is not related to subdomains - what you're looking for is [`server_name`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name) in the stage above `location`. Read more about [server names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) in the documentation.

**note**: this is untested code;

I'd try something like the following:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    # We require the expression in double quotes so the `{` and `}` aren't passed as directives.
    # The `\w` matches an alphanumeric character and the `{7}` matches at least 7 occurrences
    server_name  "~^\w{7}\.example\.com";

    location / {
        # do_stuff...;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    # We require the expression in double quotes so the `{` and `}` aren't passed as directives.
    # The `\w` matches an alphanumeric character and the `{1,6}` matches no more than 6 occurrences
    server_name  "~^\w{1,6}\.example\.com";

    location / {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

As I said the above is untested but should give you a good basis to go on. You can read more about the [`PCRE`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions) regular expressions nginx users and [server_names](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This worked. However, I needed to flip the order of the 'server' blocks i.e. I had to put the 'allow' section first (at least 7 char match) before the 'block' section (404 for 6 characters or less)

Comment: Damn - so close to being correct without trying :-) Have updated my answer. Cheers